# Rest API in Flutter Login

Tags: flutter, http, authentication, dart, rest

When I give header and body information inside my http request, it redirects automatically to next page even if i dont give any login credential in my Mobile App.

```
Future<Login> fetchLoginData() async {
    final http.Response response = await http.post(
      'http://lmsapi.design.net:88//api/login/login',
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization': 'Basic XfnatLYBaDO2AKP6KfcIJg=='
      },
/*        body: {
          'companycode': 'ABC1001',
          'deploymentcode': 'ui11'
        }*/
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // then parse the JSON.
      return Login.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
      } else {
      // then throw an exception.
      throw Exception('Failed to load Data');
    }
  }
```

Can someone help me how to pass header and body inside my http request?

Comment: This might have to do more with the way your handling the login state, can you post the code where you're calling this function and transitioning to the next screen?

Answer (score 1):

The issue doesn't seem to be about handling the http response and leans more toward on how the navigation to the next page is handled. You'd need to check if `fetchLoginData()` returns the response. Future callback can be handled by using `fetchLoginData().then()` for example.

```dart
fetchLoginData().then((Login? loginData){
  if(loginData!=null){
    // Handle Navigation
  }
});
```

Then you may consider implementing the navigation once you got a successful response from fetchLoginData()